# NoSuchMethodException when using reflection

Tags: java, class, unit-testing, methods

Interface...

```
package com.filter.tool
public interface Tool extends Resource {
...
    List findTools(int[] sizes, int counts);
}
```

Code...

```
package com.filter.tool.impl;
class Tool extends Resource implements com.filter.tool{ //default class (not visible)
Tool(Log log, Key key, Def def, Init init, Collection items) {
    super(log, key, def, init, null, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, null, 0, false, items);
}
...
   public List findTools(int[] sizes, int counts) {
            ....
   }
...
}
```

In toolTest

```
package com.jtest.tool;
import com.filter.tool

public class ToolTest {

@Test
public void test(){
    int[] sizes = {1,2};
    int counts = 1;
    try { 
        Class<?> cls = Tool.class;
        Constructor<?> constructor = cls.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Tool tool = (Tool) constructor.newInstance();
        List pref = tool.findTools(sizes, counts);
        System.out.println(pref);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the test I got ..

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.filter.tool.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2715)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1987)
    at com.att.lpp.prov.jtest.resman.impl.PoolTest.test(PoolTest.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

But if I change the package name from the toolTest it would warn me and tried to make me change the visibility of the code. I dont want to change the code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import com.filter.tool.impl.Tool` in your test?

Comment: is not visible, if i import manually i got an error saying "change Tool to public"

Comment: how can something implement a package? `class Tool extends Resource implements com.filter.tool`. This is invalid code. There is too much uncompilable code for anyone to give you a correct answer.

Comment: because interface name and class name is the same, the code is compilable and it ran fine. Just writing the test for this is getting me stucked

Answer (score 1):

First: it seems, due to import in your test class, it tries to look for a constructor for an Interface instance, because com.filter.tool.Tool is the Tool interface, not a class. You have to rename your class or interface, to make it clearer or to do something with packages...

And the second: you have a constructor with arguments in your Tool class, that means, that you don't have a default one yet. But your test uses reflection to get a default constructor without arguments. You have to modify your test method logic, to make it looking for the constuctor with arguments, for that you have to call getDeclaredConstructor with arguments classes array like:

```
Class[] cArg = new Class[5];
cArg[0] = Log.class;
cArg[1] = Key.class;
...
Constructor<?> constructor = cls.getDeclaredConstructor(cArg);
```